# Show a button next to an element inside TinyMCE

Tags: javascript, jquery, tinymce

I want to show a button (for example, span.mybutton) next to every instance of a specified element (for example, a table) in TinyMCE—and then, when that button is clicked, grab that specific element's html, process it, and update it in the editor.

I can handle the processing, but I can't figure out how to display the button and pass in grab the specific element's html. If I do this, for example, it adds the html of span.mybutton to TinyMCE as if it were regular content, which I don't want:

```
jQuery('iframe#content').contents().find('table').append('<span class="mybutton">My button</span>');
```

Here's what I'm trying to do:

```
function processElement( element, values ) {
      // do stuff to the table html (I don't need help with this part)
      return element;
}


function appendButtonToTinyMCEElement ( button, element ) {

     // put button next to all instances of the specified element in TinyMCE
     // (in this case, put span.mybutton at the corner of all tables)

}


$('.myhelperbutton').click(function(){

      var element = ??? // get content of the element whose button was clicked
      var element = processElement( element );
      // send element back to TinyMCE (not sure how)

});
```

So, my two questions are: 
How can I display the button in the right place without affecting the html that gets saved in TinyMCE? And, when the button is clicked, how do I get/set just that element from TinyMCE?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you wish to grab all table DOM elements, and place a button next to it which does some stuff.

Below is my first thought. I am going to make convenient assumptions to make it easier, but let me know if I made some wrong assumptions somewhere. I also don't know how much javascript/jquery you already know, so let me know if I didn't explain something clearly.

```
jQuery('iframe#content').contents().find('table').each(function(index, element) {
    // create a new button.
    var $btn = $('<input type="button" class="mybutton"></input>');

    function action() {
        // This is using the `processElement` function you defined in your question,
        // I am applying it to the specific table just grabbed.
        processElement(element);
    }
    $btn.click(action);

    // This should append the button. See http://api.jquery.com/after/
    $(element).after($btn[0]);
});
```

Let me know if this works for you or not.

Comment: It looks like this creates a button variable but I don't see any code that displays it. That's the key part I need to figure out. Re multiple tables, perhaps we can use the index in the each function to get the number of the table we're working with. Like `<input type="button" tableindex="'+index+'"></input>'`

Comment: Also, note - the `'h3'` was a typo in my question. It should be `find('table')`.

Comment: oops. I did forget to actually add the button didn't I :). See my edits. I also assume that the `<span class="mybutton">My button</span>` was supposed to be an input element. But if that's what you mean to insert as the button, then just put that code in place of my `<input type="button" class="mybutton"></input>`

Comment: The problem is that this inserts it into the content—so, the button is editable, deletable, and gets saved in the post. The question is how to position the button there but have it "live" elsewhere in the DOM.

Comment: I am afraid I don't understand. an `<input>` field of `type="button"` is not "editable in any way by the user. Nor can the user "delete" the button in any way. What do you mean by "editable/deletable"? by the user? And is this question of mine relevant to your main issue?